# Data type Mismatch in Criteria Expression , When inserting Data in MS Access?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Hello guys Can you help me , i'm having problem inserting data into my database , I'm getting error with cmd.executenonquery() line it says "Data type mismatch in criteria Expression" , Do i need to change something on my code?

**Here's my code :**

```vb
Private Sub Button4_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click

    Dim insertI As String = "INSERT INTO Infos (FirstName,SurName,MiddleName,Birthdate,Age,Gender,HomeAddress,CityAddress,BaranggayAddress,TelephoneNumber,EmailAdd1,Birthplace,MobileNumber1,MobileNumber2,Yearlevel,Course,Emailadd2) 
          VALUES (@FirstName,@SurName,@MiddleName,@Birthdate,@Age,@Gender,@HomeAddress,@CityAddress,@BaranggayAddress,@TelephoneNumber,@EmailAdd1,@Birthplace,@MobileNumber1,@MobileNumber2,@Yearlevel,@Course,@Emailadd2)"
    Dim cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertI, con)

    '--
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@FirstName").Value = fname.Text.ToString

    '--
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SurName", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@SurName").Value = Sname.Text.ToString

    '--
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@MiddleName").Value = Mname.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthdate", OleDbType.Date)
    cmd.Parameters("@Birthdate").Value = Datetxt.Text.ToString

    '--
    'Domainupdown 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Age", OleDbType.Integer)
    cmd.Parameters("@Age").Value = Agetxt.Text.ToString
    '--
    'Combobox
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Gender").Value = gendertxt.Items.ToString

    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HomeAddress", OleDbType.LongVarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@HomeAddress").Value = homaddtxt.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityAddress", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@CityAddress").Value = Cityadd.Text.ToString
    '-
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BaranggayAddress", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@BaranggayAddress").Value = brgyadd.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TelephoneNumber", OleDbType.Currency)
    cmd.Parameters("@TelephoneNumber").Value = telnumtxt.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd1", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@EmailAdd1").Value = emailaddtxt.Text.ToString

    '--
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Birthplace", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Birthplace").Value = birthPtxt.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber1", OleDbType.Numeric)
    cmd.Parameters("@MobileNumber1").Value = mobilenum1txt.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNumber2", OleDbType.Numeric)
    cmd.Parameters("@MobileNumber1").Value = mobilenum2txt.Text.ToString
    '-- 
    'Combobox
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Yearlevel", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Yearlevel").Value = Yrlvltxt.Items.ToString

    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Course", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Course").Value = coursetxt.Text.ToString
    '--

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd2", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@EmailAdd2").Value = emailadd2txt.Text.ToString

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to provide correct data types. Example: `cmd.Parameters("@Birthdate").Value = Date.Parse(Datetxt.Text)` and `cmd.Parameters("@Age").Value = Integer.Parse(Agetxt.Text)`.

Comment: can you expand that ? I already tried your suggestion but i'm still getting the error

Comment: Update you're question with the new code you've written.

Comment: I already got it , I changed the whole code oh, and add some brackets to somefields : "[mobilenum1] AND [mobilenum2] "

Changed the code to:
 Ex. "cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmailAdd2", OleDbType.VarWChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@EmailAdd2").Value = emailadd2txt.Text.ToString"

to 

cmd.parameters.addwithvalue("@EmailAdd2", emailadd2txt.text) 

it's working

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Do not use `AddWithValue` unless you actually **add** a value. As is, you're adding `OleDbType.VarWChar` when you should have added `emailadd2txt.Text`. Try this instead: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@EmailAdd2", OleDbType.VarWChar).Value = emailadd2txt.Text`.

Comment: The code you've suggested and the new code that i'am using is both working  without  problem.